# How to create a NSImage from a NSData with Swift

Tags: swift, image, nsimage

Sorry to ask such a simple but this is my first program in Swift... I try to create a NSImage from a NSData that contains a JPEG image I loaded from disk (URLs are in an array name choseFiles[]).

The compiler issues an error on the second and I'm stuck:'NSData' is not implicitly convertible to 'Data'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Thank you

```
let imageAsNSData = NSData(contentsOf: chosenFiles[0])  // UIKit/UIImage for iOS not MacOS !
let imageAsNSImage = NSImage(data: imageAsNSData)
if (imageAsNSImage) {
   // image could be created from NSData
   //

} else {

   // image could NOT be created from NSData
   //

}
```

----- EDIT -----

I tried

`let imageAsNSImage = NSImage(data: imageAsNSData! as Data)
            if (imageAsNSImage != nil) {`

which seems to work (at least for the compiler). Am I correct?

Comment: First thing it is not NSImage , it is UIImage

Comment: Don't think so. Already tried and found that UIImage is for iOS, not MacOS.

Comment: K I thought u are talking about iOS.

Comment: U should specify in your question which OS you are talking to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use swift Data to get your image:

```
do {
    let imageData = try Data(contentsOf:  chosenFiles[0])
    NSImage(data: imageData)
} catch {
    print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now in swift3 NSData is replaced by Data. When you are downloading image from url store it as Data not NSData.

```
imageView.image = NSImage.init(data: data! as Data)
```

Comment: Bridge cast is a bad suggestion. Use `Data(contentsOf`